Expected value of a time series
I'm reading the fourth edition of Shumway and Stoffer's "Time Series Analysis and Its Applications" and I got stuck trying to determine the expected value or mean function of a simple time series using the definition that is given.
Indeed, Definition 1.1 gives us the mean function of a time series $x_t$ as $\mu_{xt}=E(x_t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_t(x)dx$, where $f_t(x)=\frac{\partial F_t(x)}{\partial x}$ is the density function and $F_t(x)=P\{x_t \leq x\}$ is the distribution function.
Now if, for example, we take $x_t=\beta_1 +\beta_2t$, it makes sense to me intuitively that $E(x_t)=\beta_1+\beta_2t$, but I don't see how to use the definition to get there. How do I determine the density function or the distribution function of a time series like this? Or is that not the point?

It is right that when $x_t$ is equal to a constant, the expectation of $x_t$ is equal to the value of the constant.
The formula of Definition 1.1 in the aforementioned reference applies only when $x_t$ has a density, which is not the case of constants.

Thanks a lot for the answer!
A constant with respect to what? Because $x_t$ isn't a constant with respect to time, for instance. Also, why does a constant not have a density? I guess these things must be very elementary concepts from statistical theory, but I'm not used to them...

Constant with respect to $\omega$, I mean, non-random. It is indeed not constant with respect to $t$ and in any case, the discussion is for a fixed $t$. If a random variable $Y$ has a density, then for each real number $x$, $P(Y=x)=0$. This cannot be the case for a constant random variable.
